# Which Silverlight Control Set is better? Telerik or ComponentArt?

Tags: silverlight, controls

Which Silverlight Control Set is better?   Telerik or ComponentArt?

I have used ComponentArt, but I just reviewed Telerik and it looks like they might have better functionality for the same price.

If you have used both, then please let me know your opinion.

Comment: Guess you can throw in http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/ in there to maybe?

Comment: pretty subjective question, but i'd love to hear folks' opinions as well. @joe: you may want to consider changing this to a community wiki to stop people from trying to close down the question.

Comment: and maybe NOV Controls:
http://examplesnovsilverlight.nevron.com/

Answer (score 4):

ive been using Telerik controls for about 3 years. at this point i dont plan on doing any UI work without them...ever.

- Support team is amazing
- large dev community
- tight integration with VS
- releases are in step with MS releases
- NO LICENSE REQUIRED ON INDVIDUAL MACHINES JUST THE DLLS

i have no idea what the gent who replied they are difficult to install/unistall from a project is talking about...honestly. in regards to "replacing a radpanel with something light weight takes a day" they are built on top of aspnet ajax and actually have more features and performance wise (in respect to xmlhttp panel) they are much faster. aspnet does full page cycle its not even ajax its just a trick to surpress the page blink. same traffic can be seen in fiddler with or without them. much less with telerik.

as far as SL controls go. they are without any doubt the best on the market

Comment: i've used telerik for about 2 years, and componentart for the past 3 months. i can say that componentart is far inferior to telerik, the code is really trash, lots of sealed classes, no way to override / modify behavior. the telerik stuff was just way better, made my work so much simpler. sucks im stuck with componentart here

Comment: Hi @Shawn. Now is 2011. Are you still using ComponentArt? Has it improved at all?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I have found is to try out [Telerik's controls](http://www.telerik.com/download.aspx) yourself and you will be happy:) They offer a 60 day trial period that can even be extended and you can get support during the trial period.

Answer (score 0):

I've inherited codebases infested with Telerik garbage in the past, and I would strongly recommend avoiding their stuff at all cost.

The one good thing I can say about them is that it only takes about a day of effort to remove their terrible Ajax RadPanel stuff and replace it with something lightweight and sane.

I've not tried their Silverlight stuff, but having seen the quality of their other products, I don't plan on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I used Telerik controls for AJAX in my projects in the last couple of years and so far I do not have any complaints. My productivity boosted to a great extent and my clients are very happy with the results.
Jason, I do not know why you consider the Telerik AJAX controls as a low quality toolset - the ajax panels are simply wrappers around the asp UpdatePanels with some thingies that helps you manage async requests. Furthermore, their ajax manager is quite handy when you want to define declarative ajax relations through the designer or initiate ajax requests from the client and intercept them on the server with simplified coding.

I am beginning to evaluate their Silverlight toolset as well for some of my future projects and at this point my impressions are rather positive than negative (compared to ComponentArt).

Dick

Comment: The "my clients" probably explains why you like these controls and I don't.  "My users" don't like the multi-MB downloads for the initial page, nor the similarly-sized downloads for AJAX updates.  Whether that's the fault of Telerik or inherent in the underlying "Rich" controls from .NET is debatable, but ultimately moot, since neither should be considered when building a site for the public internet.  So, to clarify, if you're building an intranet app or something for a client with close to no traffic, go nuts with this sort of Rich control.  If not, don't.